# Toolbar error on Java android studio application

Tags: android, toolbar

I'm trying to add a toolbar to my home activity on my app. I have the following problem. `error: incompatible types: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.` . I have "toolbar" underlined in red.

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R2iq.png)

Any idea what could be? I found only that it could be an import problem but I already try changing it with no success.

Thanks.

This is my XML code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarTheme"
        android:theme="?actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/menubuttonofthreelines_79781">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my HomeActivity code:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,
                  R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toogle);
toogle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java activity file remove the the Toolbar from `android.widget` package

```
import  android.widget.Toolbar;
```

And add androidx Toolbar from `androidx.appcompat.widget` package instead

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate project to AndroidX. You are using Toolbar from androidx but you passed to setSupportActionBar Toolbar form  android.widget.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate